# Laravel (Beginner) - Display data from a selected row from a dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-5, dropdown

This is **Controller.php**

```
public function dropdown($id)
  {

    $stations = Station::lists('station_name','id');
    return view('stations.show')->withStation($station);
    return view('stations.dropdown',compact('stations', 'selectedStation','selectedStation'));

  }
```

This is the **view.php**

```
{{ Form::select('station',$stations,null,['class' => 'form-control']) }} 
            <br>
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])){


            $selectedStation = $_GET['station'];
            echo $selectedStation;echo "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "not working";
        }
    ?>
```

corresponding Database table.
     [image: database image]

This gives me a drop-down like in the below image.[image]

When a station is selected it displays only "id" of the selected station. How to retrieve other columns of the selected station ?.

Comment: You only fetch the id and column from your database. I believe the list method just generates a associative array using "key" and "value" and is used to be a handy helper to make dropdown lists and so forth. So the question is what do you want to accomplish? Why do you need the other values? Perhaps another method on the eloquent model class is more suited for your  needs -> ( `https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent` )

Comment: i need to display them as a table.. for suppose if we select a station.. it should display all the station columns in a row...

Answer (score 0):

Many ways that you can tackle this and I have also made some assumptions.
Your list (it would seem) only contains the name & the id.

I assume that you don't want to reload the page when you get the information for the specific item that you have chosen in the dropdown.

Here are the first 2 options that come to mind.

1.) AJAX - Use javascript framework like jQuery and monitor `change()` for the select, on change get the `id` and fire it to another route in Laravel which takes the ID and returns some more information in JSON. You can then use JS to display this to your users as you please.

2.) Preloaded JSON - Write new DB Query that gets all the information that you want and store it in `JSON` format inside some `<script>` tags. It wont be viewable to the user. Then you can use jQuery or other JS framework to grab that data again on `change()`

Part 2 will be faster, and if you have got 100,000s records i would advise that for perf.

Apologies if I totally misunderstood the question, it seems like you need a JS solution rather than Laravel/PHP solution. (Without a bad UX) if you did wan't more data you would need to post it and the fetch data from DB on new request.

Comment: even in php it's fine.. but the problem is I'm not sure how to display the other column data for the selected station. thank you for the suggestions..

Comment: Amend the model reference getting the stuff from the db. `$stations = Station::lists('station_name','id');` probably wants to be `:all()` which will return all rows.

Answer (score 0):

To display all the columns of all stations you can do the following.
Please note, doing this you fetch all which may not be necessary and there may be better methods available on the eloquent model class depending on what you are trying to do.

**Controller**

```
public function showTable()
{
    //Fetch all stations from the database
    $stations = Station::all();
    //Return fetched data to the view
    return view('stations.show', ['stations' => $stations]);
}
```

**View - stations/view.blade.php**

```
<ul>
@foreach ($stations as $station)
    <li>{{$station->station_name}} - {{$station->rainfall}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

For more information and examples about the eloquent model class you can check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent